# Get the value after a specific symbol in each column of the table

Tags: awk, sed, extract, cut

let's consider the following table

```
  #frame    x1:1    y1:5    z2:3    m1:13    n3:35
  1         130.31  23.2    44.1    32.7     54.3
  ....
  ....
```

I want to get the value present after the colon(:) symbol in each column. Thus the outcome will be from 2nd column 1, 3rd column 5, 4th column 3, 5th column 13, and 6th column 35. i.e. the output will look like

```
    1 5 3 13 35
```

Comment: No Sir, this gives me all the data set. I only wanted to get the value present after the colon symbol in each column.

Comment: Please provide desired output as text

Comment: Hi, the desired output will be just a value that is present after the colon symbol in each column. So basically for the 2nd column, the value will be 1, similarly for the 3rd column, the value will be 5, and so on.

Comment: Don't describe the desired output in a comment, **show us** the desired output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 's/\S+://gp' file
```

Delete any non-whitespace characters followed by a colon, globally and print the result only if there is a match.

Or if you only want the values following `:`, then:

```
sed -En '/:/{s/[^:]*//;s/\S*://gp}' file
```

Comment: Hi Sir, this partially serves my purpose as the output looks like "#frame 1 5 3 13 35". However, I wanted to get only "1 5 3 13 35". Thank you.

Comment: @AkashMondal then just delete the first field - `sed -En 's/\s*\S+\s*//;s/\S+://gp' file`

Answer (score 1):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
  #frame    x1:1    y1:5    z2:3    m1:13    n3:35
  1         130.31  23.2    44.1    32.7     54.3
  ....
  ....
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT=":[^[:space:]]+"}NF{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){$i=substr($i,2)};print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1 5 3 13 35
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` via `FPAT` variable that it should consider `:` followed by 1 or more (`+`) non (`^`) - whitespace (`[:space:]`) to be column. Then for each line having any column (`NF`) I iterate over these columns using `for` loop and replace its' content with content with value starting at 2nd character, i.e. I discard leading `:`, when that is done I `print` line (contents of columns sheared by space characters)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*